# jQuery child and ancestor selector not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css-selectors

In jQuery, child selectors supposedly work in IE 7+, but a particular selector path is not working for me in IE 8.  Given the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.a > div a').text("Found!");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href="#">Not Found</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

"Not Found" remains in the `<a/>` element.  If I remove one of the divs, the selector does work.  Is my selector incorrect, or is this a known or discovered jQuery bug?  We're using version 1.4.1, but I just verified the same behavior occurs in jQuery 1.4.4.

Comment: works for me on IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/Hqyxp/

Comment: Works for me as well. When you execute this line 'alert($);', does it alert anything?

Comment: Does it work for either of you when not running it in jsfiddle?  It works for me there as well, but it's not working when running it directly in my browser.  Does jsfiddle run it in an external browser?

Comment: Oh, and `alert($)` works as expected.  Remember, the text changes if one of those child divs is removed, so jQuery itself is working.

Comment: I filed a bug, and it turned out it was a duplicate of this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, I don't have a windows machine right now. But if it really is not working in IE8 you probably should fill a bug.

Anyway, to avoid the selector you can always use

```
$('.a > div').find('a').text('Found!');
```

Comment: I filed a bug, and apparently this is a known issue.  Your workaround is sound (though I can't use it), so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Jacob: may I ask why you can't use it ?

Comment: My code is passed "opaque" jQuery selector strings from another source so it can apply a theme to the page; it isn't directly doing the selection itself.  Your code would work, but I'd have to actually parse the selectors through JavaScript so I'd know to split up the selection code.